# Working with SMB shares causes Finder to freeze

Tags: macos, finder, smb

I have my NAS on a Debian Bullseye with SMBD 4.13.5. I am up to date on all my Macs with MacOS 11.4

I mount the SMB share through Finder and often when accessing or copying to the SMB share Finder will freeze and nothing can resolve it except rebooting the mac. Sometimes Finder can be forced to relaunch, but SMB shares will not work after that. Forcing unmount with either `umount` or `diskutil` also freeze.

Transfer speeds are fast when working at 170MB/s and I can transfer using rsync/ssh without any issue.

Per the recommendation of another AskDifferent post, I added this file to my Mac with no improvement:

```
$ cat /etc/nsmb.conf

[default]
signing_required=no
```

I share from the Debian box with very basic config of the `smbd.conf`

```
[example]
comment = example
path = /example
browseable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = no
valid users = user1
```

Answer (score 1):

I really don’t know how this works, but for me, removing the smb:// header fixed the issue (so only the host name or ip).

If someone can explain why this works, please edit or comment. However, this change fixed the issue for me.